# How to make contains method case insensitive in linq to sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to use like type operator in linq to sql, i used contains method to achieve it, but it is case sensitive, suggest me something.

The contains method is case sensitive but I want my query to be case insensitive . I tried to use `IndexOf()` method also but it is giving exception.

```
public static List<string> GetDecodedStaticMsg(string filterMsg)
 {
     try
     {
         var q1 = (from decodemsg in Em.StaticMessages
                   where decodemsg.Message.Contains(filterMsg)
                   select
                   decodemsg.MessageId
                   ).ToList();

                  return q1;

     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
                return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I believe it's dependent on your database's collation.  If your database uses a case-sensitive collation, then your string comparisons will be case-sensitive.

Comment: How about `decodemsg.Message.ToLower().Contains(filterMsg.ToLower())`?

Comment: Because to performance issue , its not allowed me to convert my string to lower or upper case , suggest me some other effective way

Comment: Well you could create a stored procedure

Comment: What query provider do you use? Entity Framwork?

Comment: yes , i am using entity framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CompareInfo` member from the `CultureInfo` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), try this :

```cs
public static List<string> GetDecodedStaticMsg(string filterMsg)
{
     try
     {
         var q1 = (from decodemsg in Em.StaticMessages
                   where culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(decodemsg.Message, filterMsg, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0
                   select
                   decodemsg.MessageId
                   ).ToList();

                  return q1;

     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
                return null;
     }
}
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/3759822

Comment: I doubt this would work for any Linq to SQL provider.

Comment: It is not working as indexof() is not allowed , i shared it in question itself

Answer (score 0):

We could use SqlMethods.Like for doing case insensitive search

```
public static List<string> GetDecodedStaticMsg(string filterMsg)
 {
     try
     {
         var q1 = (from decodemsg in Em.StaticMessages
                   where SqlMethods.Like(decodemsg.Message, $"%{filterMsg}%")  //Changes here
                   select
                   decodemsg.MessageId
                   ).ToList();

                  return q1;

     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
                return null;
     }
 }
```